# Separating axis theorem implementation works not exact

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
bool SAT(body& b1, body& b2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < b1.edges.size(); i++)
    {
        vec2& v1 = b1.edges[i];
        vec2& v2 = i < b1.edges.size() ? b1.edges[i + 1] : b1.edges[0];

        vec2 edge = v2 - v1;

        vec2 axis = edge.left();

        axis.normalize();

        vec2 proj1 = proj(b1, axis);
        vec2 proj2 = proj(b2, axis);

        float dist = interval_dist(proj1.x, proj1.y, proj2.x, proj2.y);

        if (dist > 0) return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b2.edges.size(); i++)
    {
        vec2& v1 = b2.edges[i];
        vec2& v2 = i < b2.edges.size() ? b2.edges[i + 1] : b2.edges[0];

        vec2 edge = v2 - v1;

        vec2 axis = edge.left();

        axis.normalize();

        vec2 proj1 = proj(b1, axis);
        vec2 proj2 = proj(b2, axis);

        float dist = interval_dist(proj1.x, proj1.y, proj2.x, proj2.y);

        if (dist > 0) return false;
    }


    return true;
}


float interval_dist(float minA, float maxA, float minB, float maxB)
{
    if (minA < minB) 
    {
        return minB - maxA;
    }
    else {
        return minA - maxB;
    }
}

vec2 proj(body& b, vec2& axis)
{
    float min = dot(b.edges[0], axis);
    float max = min;

    for (int i = 1; i < b.edges.size(); i++)
    {
        float dt = dot(b.edges[i], axis);

        if (dt < min)min = dt;

        if (dt > max)max = dt;
    }

    return vec2(min, max);
}

vec2::vec2 left()
{
    return vec2(-y, x);
}
```

The result I get can significantly differ from what I see on the screen. Two bodies can be quite far from each other (not very much though), but SAT returns true. Or two bodies can get into each other so SAT is "late" for actual collision moment.

All vertices in bodies are defined in counter clockwize order and are transformed into world space.

Any Ideas?

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOI36.png)

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiXcz.png)

Screenshots were taken while debug mode right after checking if SAT returned true.

Answer (score 0):

In `SAT`, this doesn't seem to do what was intended:

```
vec2& v2 = i < b1.edges.size() ? b1.edges[i + 1] : b1.edges[0];
```

`i < b1.edges.size()` will always be true since `i` never reaches `b1.edges.size()`. Instead you probably wanted to compare against `b1.edges.size() - 1`:

```
vec2& v2 = i < b1.edges.size() - 1 ? b1.edges[i + 1] : b1.edges[0];
```

The same happens in the second loop.

Comment: sorry, that's problem only in code posted. In my original code I did it right, but still get this error.